# Avoid Error when No Results from Entity Query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a simple Entity query:

```
Dim rhcexists = From p In dbContracts.Signatures _
                    Where p.StudentID = people_code_id _
                    And p.ContractType = "rhc" _
                    Order By p.ID Descending _
                    Select p
```

I then check whether one of the result values is more recent than six months ago using an if..then like so:

```
If rhcexists.First.SignatureDate > Date.Today.AddMonths(-6) Then
End If
```

However, if there are no results returned this will return an error. Is there a way for me to tell it to act as if the date is older than six months if there is no value at all? e.g., could I in pseudo do something like:

```
If Exists(rhcexists.First.SignatureDate, Date.Today.AddMonths(-8)) > Date.Today.AddMonths(-6) Then
```

End If

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `First` extension method, which will go bang if there are no results. You could do:

```
Dim first = rhcexists.FirstOrDefault()
If first IsNot Nothing AndAlso first.SignatureDate > Date.Today.AddMonths(-6) Then
    ' Do stuff here
End If
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return `Nothing` if there are no results, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: How do I set a FirstOrDefault value that is a date? It keeps coming back saying that webHousing.Signatures can't be a Date.Today.

Comment: @davemackey: It's not clear exactly what you mean. You're calling `FirstOrDefault()` on the *query*, so the result will be whatever type the query is returning - at a guess, a `Signature` or something like that. Note how in my code I'm using the `SignatureDate` property on `first`.

Comment: Okay, I changed it over to your code example, but then I get an error that the operator <> is not defined for this type (webHousing.Signature).

Comment: @davemackey: Try Is Not Nothing instead. You basically want the equivalent of the C# `if (first != null && ...)`

Comment: @Jon Skeet indeed the correct syntax for comparing reference types with null/nothing is `IsNot Nothing`

Comment: I still get a NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I execute the code. Here is what the code looks like now:
Dim clcfirst = clcexists.FirstOrDefault()
If clcfirst.SignatureDate IsNotNothing AndAlso clcfirst.SignatureDate > Today.AddMonths(-6) Then

Comment: @davemackey: That's not the code I posted though, is it? It's `If clcfirst IsNot Nothing`, not `If clcfirst.SignatureDate IsNot Nothing`. The point is that `clcfirst` will be a null reference if there are no values, so you shouldn't try to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

Use FirstOrDefault instead of First. Then you can setup what default returns

Comment: How does one set a value for DefaultIfEmpty? And, especially, how does one set this value to a date value? For example, if I do:
rhcexists.DefaultIfEmpty(Date.Today)
I get the error: "Value of type 'Date' cannot be converted to webHousing.Signature"